# get_or_create django model with ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have three django models:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Size(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    size = models.IntegerField()

class Obj(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size)
```

I would like to import a large amount of Obj data where many of the sizes fields will be identical. However, since Obj has a ManyToMany field, I can't just test for existence like I normally would. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
try:
    x = Obj(name='foo')
    x.sizes.add(sizemodel1) # these can be looked up with get_or_create
    ...
    x.sizes.add(sizemodelN) # these can be looked up with get_or_create
    # Now test whether x already exists, so I don't add a duplicate
    try:
        Obj.objects.get(x)
    except Obj.DoesNotExist:
        x.save()
```

However, I'm not aware of a way to get an object this way, you have to just pass in keyword parameters, which don't work for ManyToManyFields.

Is there any good way I can do this? The only idea I've had is to build up a set of Q objects to pass to get:

```
myq = myq & Q(sizes__id=sizemodelN.id)
```

But I am not sure this will even work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't make much sense because you can't add m2m relationships before an `x` is saved, but it illustrated what you are trying to do pretty well. You have a list of `Size` objects created via `get_or_create()`, and want to create an `Obj` if no duplicate obj-size relationship exists?

Unfortunately, this is not possible very easily. Chaining `Q(id=F) & Q(id=O) & Q(id=O)` doesn't work for m2m.

You could certainly use `Obj.objects.filter(size__in=Sizes)` but that means you'd get a match for an `Obj` with 1 `size` in a huge list of sizes.

[Check out this post for an `__in` exact question](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/5fd4c24ab067e7b6?pli=1), answered by Malcolm, so I trust it quite a bit.

I wrote some python for fun that could take care of this.
This is a one time import right?

```
def has_exact_m2m_match(match_list):
    """
    Get exact Obj m2m match 
    """
    if isinstance(match_list, QuerySet):
        match_list = [x.id for x in match_list]

    results = {}
    match = set(match_list)
    for obj, size in \
        Obj.sizes.through.objects.filter(size__in=match).values_list('obj', 'size'):
        # note: we are accessing the auto generated through model for the sizes m2m
        try:
            results[obj].append(size)
        except KeyError:
            results[obj] = [size]

    return bool(filter(lambda x: set(x) == match, results.values()))
    # filter any specific objects that have the exact same size IDs
    # if there is a match, it means an Obj exists with exactly 
    # the sizes you provided to the function, no more.


sizes = [size1, size2, size3, sizeN...]
if has_exact_m2m_match(sizes):
    x = Obj.objects.create(name=foo) # saves so you can use x.sizes.add
    x.sizes.add(sizes)
```

Comment: I ultimately adjusted my model a bit to reduce the problem, though the fundamental problem of matching many to many models still exists. I ended up importing the data as separate (duplicate) records. I think what I've gotten out of your and Justin's responses is that there is not a simple solution to this. This leads me to believe this action is uncommon and thus question whether I could not design the models differently to avoid this problem altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Use a through model and then .get() against that.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Once you have a through model, you can .get() or .filter() or .exists() to determine the existence of an object that you might otherwise want to create.  Note that .get() is really intended for columns where unique is enforced by the DB - you might have better performance with .exists() for your purposes.

If this is too radical or inconvenient a solution, you can also just grab the ManyRelatedManager and iterate through to determine if the object exists:

```
object_sizes = obj.sizes.all()
exists = object_sizes.filter(id__in = some_bunch_of_size_object_ids_you_are_curious_about).exists()
if not exists: 
    (your creation code here)
```

Comment: I was looking at this, but I'm not sure I follow. In this example I would create an `ObjSize` model with foreign keys to `Obj` and `Size`? Aren't I still stuck with the same problem?

Comment: Well, now you can do ObjSize.objects.get(obj=some_obj, size=sizemodel1) and such.

Comment: That gets me an Obj that contains one Size that I want, but I need the Obj that contains the set of all Size objects I specify.

Comment: Gotcha - well then you can chain filters and use .count() to see if there are as many relationships as there are candidates.

Comment: I have just edited my answer to show that you don't really need to use a through model.  I prefer using them pretty liberally because they are consistent with django's ORM behavior anyway.  But there's no dishonor in iterating through the ManyRelatedManager and asking your questions there - that's what it's there for.

Comment: exists() doesn't take an argument (it just tells you if a Qset is empty or not). Also, I think this is a much more complicated problem: it sounds like he needs a query that will return an obj that has **exactly** the m2m fields so `__in` isn't appropriate.

Comment: I was using .exists() as pseudo-code.  I realize it doesn't take arguments.  I figured that the OP would know to use .filter or .exclude.  Nonetheless, I have fixed it with the .filter route.  On your other point - yes it appears you are right.  Nonetheless, as I mentioned in my previous comment, chaining filters and using .count to see if the number of relationships matches the number of candidates is a reasonable approach.

Comment: PS: didn't see this comment till now! Sorry about that, I didn't realize it was pseudo code :)